# How to apply joomla custom login form to entire site?

Tags: php, joomla

I am developing custom component in joomla . My component has it's own login form.The requirement is when I logged in custom component login form it is applied to entire site (All the login forms are logged in).It is like [Kunena Forum](http://www.kunena.org/).

This is the Joomla's default login form:

[image]

And this is the Kunena forum login form:

[image]

When I logged here it shows like:

[image]

Now Joomla default login form also shows as logged in

[image]

How to implement like this to my component.Please help me anyone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla - I searched "joomla authentication plugin development"

Comment: Hi, I am burning my brains out trying to figure out how to override the default login page and create a custom one. I need to create an extension to allow the users to login with a Single Sign On service. The only way I found to override the com_users login output is with a template but can't find a way to do it with a module/component. Do you have a guide by hand on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create your own login system, you should use the core one, otherwise Bad Thing Could Happen™.
This leads to the question: *Why you should need another login form? Which kind of checks you have to perform?*

Anyway, you could create a plugin that hooks at the `onUserAuthorisation` event.
If the user could login, you should return `JAuthentication::STATUS_DENIED`, otherwise block him returning `JAuthentication::STATUS_DENIED`